# Left aligning single line of text

Tags: amsmath

Simple question I hope! Just want to left align "and:" with "Equations:" in Overleaf

```
Equations:
\begin{align}
A(x) \frac{\partial c_{B}(x, t)}{\partial t} &=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[J_{B, x}(x, t) A(x)\right]+A(x) \sigma_{B}(x, t)\\
\nonumber \text{and:} \\
0 &=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[J_{B, x}(x, t) A(x)\right]
\end{align}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  `\shortintertext` from `mathtool` may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating @`leandriis`'s answer:

Use this:

```
Equations:
\begin{align}
A(x) \frac{\partial c_{B}(x, t)}{\partial t} &=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[J_{B, x}(x, t) A(x)\right]+A(x) \sigma_{B}(x, t)\\
\shortintertext{\hspace{\parindent}and:} \\
0 &=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[J_{B, x}(x, t) A(x)\right]
\end{align}
```

Don't forget to add the package:

```
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools loads amsmath
```